# How to Echo only the text with "h5" tags

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to echo text with special tags "h5"
So I added this code inside function.php to echo the short description under each product

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woo_show_excerpt_shop_page', 5 );
function woo_show_excerpt_shop_page() {
    global $product;
    echo $product->post->post_excerpt;
}
```

It works but it echo all the text

So I edited the code to only pick up h5 tags

```
  add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woo_show_excerpt_shop_page', 5 );
    function woo_show_excerpt_shop_page() {
        global $product;
//pick up only h5
$html = '<h5></h5>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( $html );
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName("h5")->item(0)->textContent;
    }
```

**Now my problem is the text doesn't show up at all!
What I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: Your new code is looking for h5 tags _inside the string `"<h5></h5>"`_, and no longer references `$product->post->post_excerpt` at all.

Comment: @IMSoP Thanks for your time, well I though this way I can look in between h5 tags! what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that computers are stupid, they don't know what you *mean*, only what you *say*. So in this code:

```
$html = '<h5></h5>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( $html );
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName("h5")->item(0)->textContent;
```

The computer will load the string `'<h5></h5>'`, parse it as HTML, and then extract `h5` elements from it. At no point will it look at any other text.

What you want to do is look for `h5` elements *inside another string*, so you need to tell the computer *what* other string. Based on your first attempt, the string you want to look in is `$product->post->post_excerpt`, so *that* is the value you need in `$html`:

```
global $product;
$html = $product->post->post_excerpt;
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( $html );
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName("h5")->item(0)->textContent;
```

Comment: Now I understand, I hope someday I will be smart like you :)

Comment: @IMSoP same, all clean